# Is iPhone framework Nimbus ready for prime time yet?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, nimbus

I went thru few of the samples come with the source, feel not quite integrated but just some simple scenarios, has anyone tried using it to build a little complicated apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently using Nimbus in my app, (shameless plug, Simple In/Out) to handle attributed labels. I needed a way to detect phone numbers and email addresses in my app. The implementation works very well. If I had a complaint at all, would be to break things out a little more so I don't have to include so much of the other stuff for just attributed labels. There is a lot to like about the Nimbus framework. I haven't delved into many of the other features and functions, but my next app will more than likely include them and I will do my best to take advantage of the many other features they have included.